# Position of an element in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the `(x,y)` co-ordinates of an element in javascript. I am using `offset` of `jquery`. My code is:

```
    var offsets = $('#11a').offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var left = offsets.left;
    console.log("Coordinates of re-ranker (top,left): " +top + "," +left)
```

My element is:

```
   <p id= '11a'>
```

The value in console.log is different from the pixel values of `11a` which is something like `60px x 23px`. The value i am getting in `console.log` is something totally different and also in decimal. So what values am I getting in `offsets`? Is it different from pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

[.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns pixel values relative to the document. It is entirely possible for this method to return float values as not all sizes are pixel integers, for example:

Consider this HTML:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 33%;"></div>
```

The following command for me (for me):

```
console.log($("div").offset().left); // Outputs 276.203125
```

[jsFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/xvcVm/).

However, it is important to note the yellow box on the linked page:

> jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements **or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element**.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with
>   visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
>   tree and thus has a position that is undefined

Comment: Then why is it different from the pixel values of `p`?

Comment: Where are you getting those values from?

Comment: In javascript console, if I check the `Elements` and then put my mouse on the webpage corresponding to the id `11a`, then it is showing me some pixel values

Comment: Then you need to refer to the quoted text in my answer. Your browser will calculate this differently than jQuery as it will include the styles I highlighted

Answer (score 0):

It gets you the offsets of the element **relative to the document**!

You can learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the css values via

```
$("#11a").css("top").replace("px", ""); // You have to remove the 'px' it returns
```

Comment: I am getting something like `auto`

Comment: Because it don't have any css values (inherited), then you'll need to get the document related position with offset. An element never has the same position (in your screen) unless the fixed ones.

Comment: Like your code does: `.offset().left` and `.offset().top`.
But remember, this is the document related position.